# Date time mysql default value, indexes and primary keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, indexing

I have alot of DATE TIME columns in mysql.

Should I have the default as none or 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Also on my tables I have one primary key which is an auto increment value.

Should I add indexes on all my columns where they appear in my queries `WHERE` clause?

Is it advisable to also set up foreign keys on the PRIMARY keys, will it speed up my mysql `JOINS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I have the default as none or 0000-00-00 00:00:00

If "no date" is acceptable, then use a NULL. Having a zeroed out datetime just means you need to check for that instead of NULL, but the checks will be slower and you waste space/bandwidth to store/retrieve it.

> Should I add indexes on all my columns where they appear in my queries
>   WHERE clause?

No, only add indexes to the columns that have the largest numbers of unique values. I don't know if MySQL's query planner has gotten better than it used to be, but you may also get better performance by making sure those columns appear first in your WHERE clauses. The reasoning is that once you've restricted your query results down to a small number of rows with one where clause, the rest of the clauses can be checked about as fast with linear scans as they can with indexes, so the redundant indexes are just taking up disk and (especially important) RAM.

> Is it advisable to also set up foreign keys on the PRIMARY keys, will
>   it speed up my mysql JOINS?

No, the purpose of foreign keys is to impose validity constraints on your data, nothing to do with query performance. That being said, you should still use foreign keys where possible, as the guarantees they provide make managing your data much easier.